# How can I adjust constraints of UITableView so it does not look too big on iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard

In my `swift` iOS app I have a main menu with a container that has embedded `UITableViewController`. The latter has 4 rows, each of them contains an image and a `UILabel`. It looks as follows:

[image]

When I run it on iPhone6, it looks great:

[image]

but when I run it on iPad, it looks crowded, rows are to big:

[image]

I would like to adjust the `UITableViewController` (or rather - each cell in in) so that the `UILabel` and `UIImage` are smaller, so that the whole `UITableView` can be visible on one page here without scrolling down.
Basically - I want all 4 rows to be visible on iPad - similar to the iPhone way.

Now, couple more information:

Each `UILabel` has a custom font set up in the code:

```
    firstText.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light", size: 28.0)
    secondText.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light", size: 28.0)
    thirdText.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light", size: 28.0)
    fourthText.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light", size: 28.0)


    firstText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    secondText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    thirdText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    fourtText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

also, each element on the list has its own constraints:

[image]

and

[image]

Each row height for each tableViewCell is set up to 100, since the icon size by default is 80:

[image]

So what could I do to `shrink` the row height (or every component?) so that the whole interface looks smaller on iPad?

Comment: Your app isn't running in iPad native mode, it is running in scaled iPhone mode. Is your app supposed to be universal or iPhone only?

Comment: Just manipulate your tableView constraints to `Equal Widths` and `Equal Heights`. Then set their multiplier

Comment: @Paulw11 I wanted to design it as `iPhone only`, but it was rejected from the app store because of bad design on ipad... So now I have to adjust the whole design of the app to look at least not-that-crappy on iPads...

Comment: Unless you make it universal it is going to look pretty crappy. Especially when you run it at 2x as you have in your screen shot. Run it at 1x and it will look a bit better (but with more black around the outside)

Comment: @Paulw11 hmm ok, I tried with `1x`, but this still looks bad, the `UILabel` and `UIImage` (or basically the whole row height of each cell) didn't resize (shrink). I also tried `Marco Santarossa` answer, but it didn't work as expected. How can I scale the text size and image size (or in general - row height of each cell) so it is visible properly on iPad then?

Comment: You actually need to design your app to look ok on iPhone 4 as the iPad version of an iPhone only app is  iphone4 resolution

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: @Paulw11 how can I make images and text smaller on that resolution (while keeping other size on other devices)?

Comment: Autolayout  using size classes or use a proportional height constraint or return a row height based on the view height

Comment: @Paulw11 could you submit it as an answer? and also, if possible, could you give me some more details of how exactly should I change my constraints to my components? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `UITableViewDelegate` of your `UITableView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad ? 80 : 100
}
```

80 is just a magic number, choose whatever you want.

Comment: Marco, I tried your solution but it didn't work, all it did was to change the row height to the smaller size, but 1) it changed the row height no matter if I had an iPad similator or iPhone one, and 2) even when the row height got smaller, the label and image where just too big and not scaled down... how can I make it smaller then?

Comment: ok I discovered what's the problem in your proposed solution while applying it to my case - since I'm developing an 'iPhone only' app, check `if ==  .Pad` always returns false, no matter which device I use as the emulator...